# How to handle special cases in Angular Form Validation?

Tags: html, angular, forms, validation

I have a phone field where two formats are valid - "123-456-7890" and "+01 123-456-7890".  I have a pattern to handle the second case `Validators.pattern(/(\+\d{2})?\d{3}[\-]?\d{3}[\-]?\d{4}/)` but how to make the first case also acceptable?  As far as I can tell from the docs, the Validators only support `&&` conditions, but not `||` conditions.  Am I missing something?

Also, I'd like to make the field turn red as stuff is being entered into it if it has not yet met the validation criteria, and not annoy the user with popups along the way.  Then when he leaves the field, it stays red.  Then only when the form is submitted does it list all the fields that are wrong.  Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Use a custom ValidatorFn. Have a look at the `Forbidden Hero Name` example in the  [angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating regex to `/^(\+?\d{2}\s)?\d{3}[\-]?\d{3}[\-]?\d{4}$/` will work, and if you want a space to be optional after country code use this `/^(\+?\d{2}\s?)?\d{3}[\-]?\d{3}[\-]?\d{4}$/`.

Comment: Indeed, it worked!  Thank you!  I get the 2,3,3,4 digits.  I don't get how it is able to handle both patterns at once.  Can you explain?

Comment: I get the 2,3,3,4 digits and I see how it is able to handle both patterns at once.  What is the ^ at the beginning and the $ at the end for?  Also, the optional space doesn't seem to be working in the second format.  It fails if a space is included.

Comment: `^` means should start with. `$` means should end with. `?` means zero or one. `\s` means a white space. Adding `?` to the `\s` i.e. `\s?` means zero or one white space is allowed. `\d` means any digit. `{x, y}` means at-least `x` characters and maximum `y` characters, you can provide any one of them. For example `{,4}` means max 4 chars. `{4}` means should be 4 chars and `{4,}` means at-least 4 chars. Hope this may helpful for you.